# jQuery dando problema de "Unexpected token ;" em atribuição de variáveis

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-datatables

Eu utilizo este código abaixo para carregar na exibição de um DataTable valores de acordo com o que o usuário seleciona, não é possível utilizar o padrão do DataTable e precisa ser assim para eu poder solicitar ao servidor a quantidade necessária.
O código abaixo é como isso é feito

```
1 if ( $("#ITENSPAGINA").change() ){
2     var valor = $("#ITENSPAGINA").val();
3
4     $('#TABELACTRECEBER').DataTable({
5             "pageLength": valor;    // informa ao DataTable a quantidade que deve ser exibida na tabela
6         }
7     );
8 }
```

Desta maneira que está, funciona como esperado, mas estou com outro problema que parte desse algoritmo (linha 5)

[image: Erro do console]
[image: Linha do erro obtida no console]
(ignorar o numero da linha)
[image: Linha do erro obtida no console 2]

E como está com esse erro apresentado na primeira imagem, nenhum algoritmo JavaScript funciona após isso, para todos eu recebo o mesmo tipo de erro:
[image: Erro de JavaScript que parte do jQuery]

Agora se eu simplesmente remover o ";" (linha 5)

```
1 if ( $("#ITENSPAGINA").change() ){
2     var valor = $("#ITENSPAGINA").val();
3
4     $('#TABELACTRECEBER').DataTable({
5             "pageLength": valor
6         }
7     );
8 }
```

O código jQuery acima para de funcionar mas todos os outros JavaScripts da pagina voltam a funcionar.

Eu preciso deste código jQuery funcionando desta maneira para eu ter a minha tabela funcionando corretamente e juntamente preciso dos JavaScripts da pagina funcionando. Ou seja, todos precisam funcionar.
O que eu preciso seria apenas conseguir usar a variável sem o ";" dentro do jQuery mas ainda assim o mesmo funcionar.

*Por mais que o titulo pareça ser uma pergunta duplicada, não encontrei nenhuma pergunta com esse tipo de problema, não de **"Unexpected token ;"** mas sim de um problema de ; dentro de uma jQuery por usar uma variável indispensável.*

Comment: Você está chamando alguma variável ou função no seu código chamada "pesquisar"?

Comment: Sim, a "pesquisar" é somente um exemplo, mas se eu remover o ";" citado ela funciona como qualquer outra que também não funciona se eu deixar o ";"...

Comment: Verifica qual o valor que está sendo armazenado em sua variável valor. Pode usar o console.log pra isso

Comment: Posso te dizer com certeza que o `;` não deveria estar ai, agora, por que o código de jQuery não está funcionando não consegui identificar ainda.

Comment: A variável passa adequadamente o valor do "ITENSPAGINA" (ComboBox), lá tem pré-definido 10/25/50/100 para selecionar, e ele está passando os valores como deveria mesmo.
O que resolveria seria usar a variável sem o ; mas o jQuery não a identifica dessa maneira

Comment: "pageLength": valor; subistitua esse ; por , virgula

Comment: Desta maneira (trocar ";" por ",") a pagina não carrega as informações, é como se não mudasse o "valor"

Comment: O erro retornado pelo console é que "pesquisar" não está definido. Em qual parte do seu código você o está utilizando? Entenda que na ordem de carregamento da sua página, os scripts anteriores ao erro identificado são carregados normalmente. Experimente retirar o escopo que contém "pesquisar"

Comment: Como já disse acima, pesquisar é somente um exemplo que dá problema quando eu uso o ;